# Icon of the notification is different

Tags: android, android-notifications

I get a push notification from FCM. When my application is minimized or screen is locked, I see a title of notification : Here is your notification and different icon.

How I can change this? This is my code and how I create and display a notification I don't have this:

```
private void createNotification( String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this , NotificationActivity. class );
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Wiadomosc z serwera")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel( true )
            .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified createNotification method .

1 . Add setLargeIcon() method to set large icon .

2 . Put your own title in setTitle() method .

```
private void createNotification( String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this , NotificationActivity. class );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) /*Icon to display in the Notification Bar */
                .setLargeIcon(R.mipmap.largeicon) /*Icon to display when you scroll down notification tray */
                .setContentTitle("Your own Title") /*Notification Title which will display when you scroll down Notification tray */
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel( true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



 notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `setLargeIcon(Bitmap bitmap)` method.

```
Bitmap largeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.launcher_logo);

NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
```